# Create profile at the same time that the user is created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a profile in the DRF create function in serializer, but when save User model the next exception is triggered

`ValueError: "<Usuario: Some Name>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

This is my configuration background over python 3
Django == 1.11
DRF == Django rest framework

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, firstname, lastname, password, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not firstname:
            raise ValueError(u'The firstname is required.')

        user = self.model(
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            last_login=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

class Usuario(
    AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,
    TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel
):

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Usuario, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = PerfilSerializer(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validate_data):
        user_data = validate_data
        profile_data = validate_data.pop('profile')

        usr = Usuario(**user_data)
        usr.save()

        profl = Profile(**profile_data)
        profl.save()
        profl.user.set(usr)

        return usr
```

I want to get the model with the user instance and the profile created

Comment: add a post_save signal to User model.

Comment: The problem is in the request data 'cuz I have another many to many relation

`class Usuario(
    AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,
    TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel
):
    empresas = models.ManyToManyField(Companies, related_name='societies')`

And this block the insertion

Comment: try this. `profl = Profile(**profile_data)
        profl.user = user
        profl.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, just tweak your `create` on the profile serializer. Try this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Django Signals on User save.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Check out this concrete tutorial, as it solves your problem.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Glad to help you!